# How to decide the value of the sigma value to use for the SimpleITK Filter: SmoothingRecursiveGaussianImageFilter depending on the voxel size?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, itk, medical-imaging, simpleitk

I am using a code similar to this example in order to smooth voxel volume data (so from a CTA scan): https://examples.itk.org/src/filtering/smoothing/computessmoothingwithgaussiankernel/documentation
and wondering, what sigma value to use? Does it depend on the voxel size, because I have heard that the sigma value should be around 3 times the voxel size, but I am unsure, why this should be the case?

I have a voxel size of around 0.3 mm, so I have used a sigma value of around 1. This has worked decently, but I am not sure why and would like to understand this?
Thank you very much for any help, especially on wat sigma values to use or how this filter works!

Comment: This is just the Gaussian low-pass filter. Low-pass filters are smoothing filters. The “recursive” in the function name indicates which algorithm is used to compute the filtering result, but this is irrelevant to understand what the filter does or what the sigma parameter does, it just affects the computational cost. So, just read any description of the Gaussian filter to learn what it is you are applying here and what the sigma means.

Comment: I read about gaussian low pass filters by now. I know, that the sigma value will influence, how much the surrounding pixels of the targeted pixel will influence the new greyscale value and that the 2-d gaussian function will have a larger amplitude in the middle and therefore include the outer pixels less heavily for lower sigma values compared to larger. But I still do not get the relationship between the sigma value and the voxel spacing. So I would be very glad for hints in this particular direction. Thanks!

Comment: The voxel size/spacing is irrelevant for filtering. You typically specify the size in sigma in pixels. The kernel size is adjusted so you have most of the Gaussian curve sampled.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the response. But then what is the relationship between sigma and the pixel size? And the kernel size is independent of sigma as far as I understood it, so what does that have to do with the sigma and pixel relationship here? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to define the sigma in physical units, instead of in pixels, then you can use the pixel size to compute the size in pixels. For example if you want a sigma of 1um and you have 0.3um pixels, then you need a sigma of 3.33 pixels. — The kernel size can be specified independently in some tools (eg OpenCV, designed by people that don’t know any better), but you shouldn’t. Let OpenCV compute the appropriate size from the sigma for you.

Answer (score 0):

The proper choice of smoothing sigma depends on what you are trying to accomplish, not just the pixel spacing. To learn more, you could pick one of the [courses that use ITK](https://www.kitware.com/courses-in-medical-image-analysis-that-use-itk/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer + the link. I want to smooth out/ remove artifacts that stem from the segmentation process. I am wondering, if there is a theoretical expectation on what the sigma value should be? And how the sigma value is connected to the kernel size/ the matrix size? Thanks!